# Dynamically re-route all Zuul proxied requests to single URL

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I'm trying to forward all requests to my API to a single endpoint based upon some condition.

The `Gateway` app runs on port `8080`

I've created the following filter:

```
public class OutagePeriodFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "route";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return isOutagePeriod();
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();


        // if outage - redirect everyone to http://localhost:8082/outage
        try {
            String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://localhost:8082").path("/outage").build()
                                     .toUriString();
            ctx.setRouteHost(new URL(url));
        } catch(MalformedURLException mue) {
            log.error("Cannot forward to outage period website");
        }
        return null;
    }


    private boolean isOutagePeriod() {
        // returns true if outage
    }
}
```

However after making a request to `http://localhost:8080/alerts/public` my API logs show:

```
2017-03-03 16:11:30.735 EST 0037 DEBUG                    o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/outage/alerts/public'; against '/beans/'
```

For some reason it appends the original PATH to the redirect PATH resulting in a request to `/outage/alerts/public` which doesn't exist. I want to make a request to just `/outage`.

Putting a breakpoint in my filter just as the `ctx.setRouteHost()` is called shows that correct URL (`http://10.50.36.43:8082/outage/`).

My `application.properties`:

`zuul.routes.api.path=/api/**
zuul.routes.api.url=http://localhost:8082/`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, use PRE_TYPE instead of ROUTE_TYPE (aka "route")

```
@Override
public String filterType() {
    return FilterConstants.PRE_TYPE;
}
```

Second, specify correct filterOrder

```
@Override
public int filterOrder() {
    return FilterConstants.SEND_FORWARD_FILTER_ORDER;
}
```

Third, you need to remove URI containing "/alerts/public", which is appended to the routeHost by zuul

```
@Override
public Object run() {

    ctx.set("requestURI", "");

    // your code

    return null;
}
```

Finally, override forwarding url in the code (//your code). And you have to specify at least one route (cause zuul filters don't work if there are no routes) to proxy "not outaged" requests to the same host **8080** like this

```
zuul.routes.api.path=/api/**
zuul.routes.api.url=http://localhost:8080/api
```

IMHO, zuul is not a very convenient way to do this.

Comment: Can you suggest a convenient way to do this?

Comment: Pasan Sumanaratne, I didn't research this problem. But the first what came to my mind is Interceptor.I asked my colleague about this, and he suggest to refer to spring-cloud-gateway. Maybe it will help.